# check if database contains two people with the same age and print it

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a lot of people with the same age in a database and I want to print the people with the same age For example:

```
Table people:
Name         Age
Gessica      12
Alice        12
Max          12
Jack         34
Federica     23
```

Now I want to print:

```
Age:12 Gessica,Alice,Max
Age:34 Jack
Age:23 Federica
```

I use Php and try pg_fetch_array function:

```
$query = pg_query($conn1, $query_impiegati);
$people=array('Gessica','Alice','Max','Jack','Federica');
        
while($row = pg_fetch_array($query)) {
    $results[] = array('Name'=>$row['Name'],'Age'=>$row['Age'] );
    for($i=0;i<count($results);$i++){
        for($j=0;j<count($masioni);$i++){
            if($people[j]==results['Age'][i]){
                echo $row["Age"];
                echo $row["Name"]<br>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could group the people's names by their age in an associative array. If you simply concatenate the names while looping over the rows you should get your final output string.

Comment: Why don't you do this in the query using `STRING_AGG()`?

Comment: The `for` loop shouldn't be inside the `while` loop.

Comment: if i use associative array i use   $dataById[$row['Age']] = []? it don't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do this aggregation in your query:

```sql
SELECT Age,
       STRING_AGG(Name, ',') AS Names
FROM people
GROUP BY Age
ORDER BY Age
```

Output:

```
Age     Names
12      Gessica,Alice,Max
23      Federica
34      Jack
```

[Demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aMbQt1svJQyNWTjNo8BfXJ/0)